# Perl: Exit if a particular line is not present in a file

Tags: perl, file-io

Before I perform certain operations on a file, I need to scan the file to see if it contains one particular line. If that line is not present anywhere in the file, I exit (and do not perform any further actions on the file).

What is the most efficient way of doing this in Perl?

Comment: Add your sample input and the expected output in the question which will make the Question more clear.

Comment: @Praveen: Question is clear. For this no need to show sample input or expected output. But OP could show his/her approach.

Comment: Since you have to read the entire file anyway to check for the presence of your "trigger" line, it might be more efficient to process the lines as you go and simply stop if you hit the trigger. That saves you from having to read the entire file twice in the worst case scenario (i.e. file doesn't contain the trigger line); since file I/O is expensive, you usually want to avoid processing the same file twice if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing with reading files is - the expensive part is always the process of reading the data.

So - read your file, break if you hit a line that matches and test if you did outside the loop;

```
my $found; 
while ( <$filehandle> ) {
    if ( m/Some Text to match here/ ) { 
        $found++;
        last;
    }
}

die "Line not present" unless $found;
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I wanted!